# The remote computer refused the network connection Error

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am getting this connection [error](https://pasteboard.co/GCJGbv0.png) when I open the web application

This is my connection string

```
   <add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=ABC-DEF;Initial Catalog=DB;
Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Also to add, the site was working fine, this error is sudden. 
I have tried restarting the `sql-server` services and also set static `tcp` port. 
Still does not work. 
Where is the error?

Comment: Maybe you can only access it on the same network?

Comment: already been on that link, tried every solution mentioned in the comments :(

Comment: In the comments??? There are over 200,000 links for that search. This is just so vague. It really requires looking at way too many things for this to be successful on an online forum. The suggestions posted are great ones, they are some of the most common reasons this might happen.

Answer (score 5):

Try one of the following

1. make sure that server and client use the same network protocol (enable TCP/IP).
2. Enable the service SQL Browser from your server.
3. Enable 'Allow remote connections' setting in the server.
4. check your server/workstation firewall so it's not blocking anything. Make sure you can access it remotely.

Comment: 2-yes, its already enabled
4-firewall is off
3-its not only about remote connection, my client is also getting the same error on his localhost

Comment: @ZhrezPain what version of sql server are you using? Express?

Comment: No, SQL server 2012

Comment: @ZhrezPain Where is the app being hosted?

Comment: Maybe he should check his IIS settings. Sorry I'm all out of ideas after this one.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

I have had same issue so wanted to share this for anyone who may come across this post in the future like I have. In my case the SQL server service would look like it is running fine but when I would try and restart the service it would hang and not be fully stopped or started and would not budge even after restarting the computer.

I resolved the issue by opening Task Manager (ctrl+shift+esc) and ending the process with the name "SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit". I could then restart the SQL server service and everything was fine again - no more error in the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Change you connect string according to the below code, where `data source=DESKTOP-6E4R4GB` is your SQL server name and `initial catalog=Referral2Cash` is your db name.

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EDMX.Model1.csdl|res://*/EDMX.Model1.ssdl|res://*/EDMX.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-6E4R4GB;initial catalog=Referral2Cash;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to sql server management studio:

1. Left pane you see server name.
2. Right click and select Property.
3. Popup will show server detail.
4. Check name property like (your_server_name\MSSQLSERVER2016)
   your connection string will be like

```xml
<add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=ABC-DEF\MSSQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=DB;
Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

OR

```xml
<add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=DB;
Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by opening Task Manager <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and ending the process with the name "SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit". I could then restart the SQL server service and everything was fine again - no more error in the web application.
Then run => services.msc => start SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)

[image: SQL Server service]

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when using SQL Express, which I resolved by noticing that I had incorrectly specified the port in the data source section of the connection string. In the connection string, I had `data source=.\SQLEXPRESS,1433;` when the port number should actually have been `1443`. This was after enabling TCP/IP over port 1443, as detailed by [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-ver15#to-enable-a-server-network-protocol).