# SQL Server Management Studio: issues with remote connections

Tags: ssms, remote-connection

I need to use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to connect to a remote server for my work. I have never used SSMS before and I did not install it myself as I do not have admin rights on my work computer. 
I have been given a Server Name and told to choose 'Database Engine' as Server Type and 'Windows authentication' in the 'Connect to Server' window. I have asked for firewall authorisation and I have been added among the users authorised to use the remote server.

However I have not been able so far to connect because every time I open SSMS and use the 'Connect to Server' interface I always get the same error:

> 'A network related  or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:TCP provider, error:0 - The remote computer refused the network connection.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1225). --> The remote computer refused the network connection"

I double checked multiple times that the server name is correct and that I have firewall authorisation and that I am an authorised user for the remote server.
It makes me think that my version of SSMS is not enabled for remote access. I checked possible solutions all over Google but with no success. One suggestion is to right-click on the server name and in the Server Properties allow the remote connection. However i do not have any server instance in the Object Explorer window so nothing on which I could right-click on.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The remote computer refused the network connection Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330714/the-remote-computer-refused-the-network-connection-error)

Comment: Have checked the SQL Server is in Started mode under services.msc?

Comment: Sounds like you should be talking to support in the business, as they have appear to have a "well oiled" process in place for granting users access to their SQL instances.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking at the same problem, I was also able to fix the issue by deleting the following registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo
```

I just renamed ConnectTo and then it started working.  Don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure there are many potential problems, but if this helps anyone, I was in a state that I could login to "localhost" but could not login to SQL Instance name (which was my machine name).

I was able to fix this by removing my machine name from this registry hive:

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo

Hope this helps at least one person.